# Como eliminar un nodo de una lista?

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo esta estructura, y necesito borrar un nodo, hasta ahora ya lo eh identificado el nodo, pero a la hora de borrar, le aplique un `delete(temp)` y un `free("temp")`, pero lo único que borra son los datos, cuando abro mi función imprimir se sigue imprimiendo la función `void desplegarNodo()` pero con los campos vacíos.

```
struct nodo{
    string nombre;
    string telefono;
    string correo;
    string direccion;
    nodo* sig;
    nodo* anterior;
    ////Inicializacion
    nodo(): sig(NULL),anterior(NULL){}
    nodo(string n, string t, string c, string d):sig(NULL),anterior(NULL), nombre(n), telefono(t), correo(c), direccion(d){}
    //impresion x nodo
    void desplegarNodo(){
     cout<<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
     cout<<"Telefono: "<<telefono<<endl;
     cout<<"Correo: "<<correo<<endl;
     cout<<"Direccion: "<<direccion<<endl;
     cout<<"-.-.-.-.-.-.-..-.-.-.-.-.--.-.-.-.-..-.-.-..-.-.--.-.-."<<endl;
    }
};
```

Esta es la función que hice para eliminar

```
void Delate(string n){
    Nodo* temp = new Nodo();
    temp = Query(n);
    if(!temp){
        cout << "El registro no existe\n";
        return;
    }
    if(temp -> sig == NULL){
        DelateLast(temp);
        return;
    }
    if(temp -> ant == NULL){
        DelateFirst(temp);
        return;
    }
    DelateDespues(temp);
}
```

Si eliminó el primero:

```
void DelateFirst(Nodo* temp){
    if(ini -> sig == fin -> sig){
        ini -> sig = NULL;
        fin -> sig = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if(isEmpty())
        return;
    ini -> sig = ini -> sig -> sig;
    ini -> sig -> ant = NULL;
}
```

Si eliminó el último:

```
void DelateLast(Nodo* temp){
    if(ini -> sig == fin -> sig){
        ini -> sig = NULL;
        fin -> sig = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if(isEmpty())
        return;
    fin -> sig = fin -> sig -> ant;
    fin -> sig = NULL;
}
```

y si elimino alguno de en medio:

```
void DelateDespues(Nodo* temp){
    Nodo* izq = new Nodo();
    Nodo* der = new Nodo();
    izq = temp -> ant;
    der = temp -> sig;
    izq -> sig = der;
    der -> ant = izq;
}
```

Mis variables de control de la lista son `ini`, que es el inicio de la lista y y fin que es el último de la lista.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [ask] y [mcve]. En concreto, podrías poner un *main* explicando como creas una lista con un par de nodos y como haces invocas el borrado de un nodo? En todo caso, cuidado que tu código tiene *memory leaks*.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que salta a mi vista es que no necesitas reservar memoria para realizar una operación de borrado. En otras palabras, no hay razón para llamar a `new` para eliminar un nodo de una lista.

Estamos trabajando con punteros, basta con hacer que las cosas apunten a los lugares correctos y lo que si hay que hacer es liberar la memoria del nodo que estamos eliminando.

Por lo que puedo deducir de tu pregunta, se trata de una lista doblemente enlazada , por lo que usualmente basta con hacer que el nodo anterior apunte al siguiente y el siguiente al anterior, tomando en cuenta solo el caso que el nodo a eliminar sea el de inicio de la lista. En ese caso, hay que hacer que el inicio de la lista sea el segundo nodo.

- Problema No. 1, en este fragmento de código

  ```
  void Delate(string n){
      Nodo* temp = new Nodo();
      temp = Query(n);
  ```

  Reservas memoria con new y en la siguiente línea apuntas a lo devuelto por la llamada a `Query`. Esto va a provocar un *memory leak*. Has reservado memoria en el *heap*, pero ya no tienes un apuntador a esa dirección de memoria, por lo que no puedes liberarla.
- Una vez tienes el nodo a eliminar, debes *enlazar* correctamente los apuntadores del nodo anterior y siguiente. Considero que es más sencillo hacerlo todo en el mismo método, sin escribir métodos especializados para esto. Por ejemplo, para enlazar todo, basta con algo como:

  ```
  if(temp -> sig != NULL) 
      temp -> sig -> ant = temp -> ant;
  if(temp -> ant != NULL) 
      temp -> ant -> sig = temp -> sig;
  ```

  Esto funcionará incluso en los extremos de la cola. Si nos encontramos en el primer o último registro, los apuntadores de los registros anterior y siguiente del nuevo primer o último registro quedarán bien.
- Luego, debes devolver la memoria que tiene el nodo actual.

  ```
  delete temp;
  ```
- No debes olvidar asignar los punteros `ini` y `fin`, si estás eliminando al inicio o al final de la lista. Tomando en cuenta esto, `Delete` podría ser algo como:

  ```
  void Delate(string n){
      Nodo* temp = new Nodo();
      temp = Query(n);
      if(!temp){
          cout << "El registro no existe\n";
          return;
      }
      if(temp -> sig != NULL) 
          temp -> sig -> ant = temp -> ant;
      if(temp -> ant != NULL) 
          temp -> ant -> sig = temp -> sig;
      if(temp == ini)
          ini = temp -> sig;
      if(temp == fin)
          fin = temp -> ant;

      delete temp;
  }
  ```

En el cuerpo de la función, la re-asignación de ini y fin puede hacerse dentro de un `else` de los primeros dos `if`. Lo he escrito de esta manera para no hacerlo más complicado, pero sería un buen ejercicio que lo re-escribieras de otra forma.